# How can I make an average calculation for integer column?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to calculate the average of an integer values column in a csv file.
I get the following error message :  `if iter(data) is data:`
`TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: The error message is pretty straightforward: `data` is an integer, so `iter(data)` doesn't make sense.  For more than that, we'll need to see your code.

Comment: The code i wrote goes like this:

Comment: import csv, pandas as pd


csv_file = csv.reader(open("C:\\Users\\talpr\\python-betting model\\england_19_20_over.csv"))
next(csv_file)


for game in csv_file:
    home_team = game[2]
    away_team = game[3]
    total_goals = game[5]

    df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\talpr\\python-betting model\\england_19_20_over.csv")
    avg = df[total_goals].mean()
    print(avg)

Answer (score 1):

Below is the standard way of calculating the average of a column in a data frame. Hope that helps.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("file_name.csv")
avg = df["column_name"].mean()
print(avg)
```